# Java XML Parsing with XStream

Tags: java, xml-parsing

My scenario is like

```
        I want it in the format 
                        <Name>fieldName</Name>
                        <Value>givenValue</Value>
```

Here fieldName is like a field of a class and givenValue is value given to the field

I'm using XStream now and I'm completely new to this. When I work on XStream it is giving like

```
<fieldName>givenValue</fieldName>
```

Please help me with the case. If it can be done in XStream then it will be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a class that holds the two fields Name and Value :

```
public class MyClass {
   private String name;
   private String value;
}
```